# PHP invisible class properties

Tags: php, class, properties

Ok I know I can have private properties which prevent a property from being used outside of the class, but is it possible to also make that property invisible outside of the class?

What I mean is, is it possible to make a way so that the property doesn't even show up if I do a `print_r()` or `foreach()` of the class?

Comment: I remember there was a discussion about this a while ago, and there were some PHP versions not showing those properties. Sadly I can't find it at the moment. Is there any special reason why would you not want them displayed? Reflection could still be used to see them.

Comment: Here, two bug reports, http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39118&edit=2 and http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35822&edit=1. As you can see in the response, it's not a bug but rather a feature.

Answer (score 0):

`global` some obscure variable names in all your methods and use them like properties

I'd never want to see it done, nor do I know why you want to hide properties from inspection by the developer, but I suppose it'd work.

Comment: I am making an active record class for php for my framework, each record is a class of its own with the data as properties. I have implemented a save method into each record but for it to work it needs to use a property with the database class inside it. I dont want to have to write extra code to remove that property when I am looping through a record, so I was hoping there was a way to hide that property. Like you I also think its unwise to use a global, I might have to though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide properties from debug functions, like print_r/var_dump. However, what you can do is to simulate properties using `__get/__set`, like this:

```
 <?php
 class MyClass {
   public function __get($name) {
      if($name == "bar") {
       /* take bar from somewhere */
      }
   }
   public function __set($name, $value) {
      if($name == "bar") {
       /* store $value somewhere */
      }
   }
 }

 $foo = new MyClass();
 $foo->bar = 1;
```

This way, you can work with $foo->bar as if it were a property, even though in fact no such property exists when you do var_dump, etc..